# Entity Framework: How to update entities with independent associations in a disconnected scenario?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to update an object with independent associations which has been changed in the UI. Loading and saving takes place in different DBContexts. I tryed the following, but now I am stuck. Every now and then I run into DBUpdateExceptions.

```
EFTestConsole.UserList.Update: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

As far as I could see, this stems from existing relations between existing objects, which were added by Entity Framework and are not contained in the navigation properties, and which I did not set to Unchanged when painting the state. But how to identify them?

This is, what I did so far:

1. Add the modified object to the DBContext and set it's state to Modified.
2. Delete the relations to those objects (existing in the database), which were removed from the navigation properties, by setting their state to Deleted.
3. Paint the state for all objects currently contained in the navigation properties: set the state of existing objects (ID > 0) and relations to Unchanged, and set the state of new objects (ID = 0) and their relations to Added.
4. Paint the state for objects, which were added to the naviagtion properties: set the  state of the object to Unchanged (if already existing: ID > 0) oder Added (if new: ID = 0), and the state of the relation to Added.
5. Remove all objects and relationship from the DBContext, which were added to the context by Entity Framework, but are not contained in the (old or current) navigation properties.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function Update(ByVal userToProcess As User) As Boolean
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
            ' Compute, which objects in the navigation properties were added resp. removed.

            ' Register userToProcess in TempDBContext.
            TempDBContext.UserDBSet.Add(userToProcess)
            TempDBContext.Entry(userToProcess).State = EntityState.Modified

            ' Fixing relationships to objects in navigation properties in 3 steps:
            ' 1. Deleting relationships to objects, which remain in database.
            For Each adg As ADGroup In UsersADGroupsToDelete
                If TempDBContext.Entry(adg).State = EntityState.Detached Then
                    adg = TempDBContext.ADGroupDBSet.Find(adg.ID)
                    TempDBContext.Entry(adg).State = EntityState.Unchanged
                End If
                TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                    .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                        userToProcess, _
                        adg, _
                        "UsersADGroupsList", _
                        EntityState.Deleted)
            Next

            For Each ug As Group In UsersGroupsToDelete
                If TempDBContext.Entry(ug).State = EntityState.Detached Then
                    ug = TempDBContext.GroupDBSet.Find(ug.ID)
                    TempDBContext.Entry(ug).State = EntityState.Unchanged
                End If
                TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                    .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                        userToProcess, _
                        ug, _
                        "UsersGroupsList", _
                        EntityState.Deleted)
            Next

            ' 2.1. Setting objects and relationships to Unchanged for all existing objects in navigation properties.
            ' 2.2. Settings objects and relationships to Added for all new objects (ID = 0) in naviagtion properties.
            For Each adg As ADGroup In userToProcess.UsersADGroupsList
                If adg.ID > 0 Then
                    TempDBContext.Entry(adg).State = EntityState.Unchanged
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            adg, _
                            "UsersADGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Unchanged)
                Else
                    TempDBContext.Entry(adg).State = EntityState.Added
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            adg, _
                            "UsersADGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Added)
                End If
            Next

            For Each ug As Group In userToProcess.UsersGroupsList
                If ug.ID > 0 Then
                    TempDBContext.Entry(ug).State = EntityState.Unchanged
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            ug, _
                            "UsersGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Unchanged)
                Else
                    TempDBContext.Entry(ug).State = EntityState.Added
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            ug, _
                            "UsersGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Added)
                End If
            Next

            ' 3. Setting objects to Unchanged, which exist in the database, but are newly related to userToProcess.

            For Each adg As ADGroup In UsersADGroupsToAdd
                If adg.ID > 0 Then
                    TempDBContext.Entry(adg).State = EntityState.Unchanged
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            adg, _
                            "UsersADGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Added)
                Else
                    TempDBContext.Entry(adg).State = EntityState.Added
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            adg, _
                            "UsersADGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Added)
                End If

            Next

            For Each ug As Group In UsersUserGroupsToAdd
                If ug.ID > 0 Then
                    TempDBContext.Entry(ug).State = EntityState.Unchanged
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            ug, _
                            "UsersGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Added)
                Else
                    TempDBContext.Entry(ug).State = EntityState.Added
                    TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                        .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                            userToProcess, _
                            ug, _
                            "UsersGroupsList", _
                            EntityState.Added)
                End If
            Next

            ' EntityFramework adds more objects and relationships to DBContext than are contained within the navigation properties.
            ' These are to be deleted now.
            Dim TempGroupForType As Group = New Group
            Dim TempGroupType As System.Type = TempGroupForType.GetType()
            Dim TempADGroupForType As ADGroup = New ADGroup
            Dim TempADGroupType As System.Type = TempADGroupForType.GetType()
            Dim TempUserForType As User = New User
            Dim TempUserType As System.Type = TempUserForType.GetType()

            For Each e As System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry(Of Modelbase) _
                In TempDBContext.ChangeTracker.Entries(Of Modelbase)()
                Select Case e.Entity.GetType()
                    Case TempGroupType
                        Dim TempGroup As Group = TryCast(e.Entity, Group)
                        If TempGroup IsNot Nothing _
                            AndAlso TempGroup.ID > 0 _
                            AndAlso TempGroup.ParentGroup IsNot Nothing _
                            AndAlso TempGroup.ParentGroup.ID > 0 Then
                            ' Detach relations to parent groups from DBContext.
                            TempDBContext.Core.ObjectStateManager _
                                                            .ChangeRelationshipState( _
                                                                TempGroup, _
                                                                TempGroup.ParentGroup, _
                                                                "ParentGroup", _
                                                                EntityState.Detached)
                        End If
                        If e.State = EntityState.Added _
                                AndAlso TempGroup IsNot Nothing _
                                AndAlso TempGroup.ID > 0 Then
                            e.State = EntityState.Detached
                        End If
                    Case TempADGroupType
                        Dim TempADGroup As ADGroup = TryCast(e.Entity, ADGroup)
                        If e.State = EntityState.Added _
                            AndAlso TempADGroup IsNot Nothing _
                            AndAlso TempADGroup.ID > 0 Then
                            e.State = EntityState.Detached
                        End If
                    Case TempUserType
                        Dim TempUser As User = TryCast(e.Entity, User)
                        If e.State = EntityState.Added _
                            AndAlso TempUser IsNot Nothing _
                            AndAlso TempUser.ID > 0 Then
                            e.State = EntityState.Detached
                        End If
                End Select
            Next

            ' Save changes to database.
            TempDBContext.SaveChanges()

            Success = True

        End Using

    Return Success
End Function
```

The objects look like this. There are users, which can belong to several groups (n:m). Optionally they can belong to AD groups (n:m), and there can be a (1:1) relation between groups and AD groups.

```
Public Class User
    Inherits ModelBase

    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property UserName() As String
    ' List of AD groups to which the user belongs.
    Public Property UsersADGroupsList() As List(Of ADGroup)
    ' List of groups to which the user belongs.
    Public Property UsersGroupsList() As List(Of Group)

    Public Sub New()
        _UsersADGroupsList = New List(Of ADGroup)
        _UsersGroupsList = New List(Of Group)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ADGroup
    Inherits ModelBase

    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
    ' List of related users.
    Public Property RelatedUsersList() As List(Of User)
    ' Reference to related group.
    Public Property RelatedGroup() As Group

    Public Sub New()
        _RelatedUsersList = New List(Of User)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Group
    Inherits ModelBase

    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
    ' List of related users.
    Public Property UserList() As List(Of User)
    ' Reference to parent group.
    Public Property ParentGroup() As Group
    ' List of children groups.
    Public Property ChildrenGroupsList() As List(Of Group)
    ' Reference to AD group.
    Public Property RelatedADGroup As ADGroup

    Public Sub New()
        _UserList = New List(Of User)
        _ChildrenGroupsList = New List(Of Group)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Finally the DBContext:

```
Public Class MyDBContext
    Inherits DBContext

    ' DBSets for the classes below.
    Public Property UserDBSet As DbSet(Of User)
    Public Property GroupDBSet As DbSet(Of Group)
    Public Property ADGroupDBSet As DbSet(Of ADGroup)
    ' Access to ObjectContext below DBContext.
    Private _Core As ObjectContext
    Public Property Core() As ObjectContext
        Get
            Return TryCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        End Get
        Private Set(ByVal value As ObjectContext)
            _Core = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal nameOrConnectionString As String)
        MyBase.New(nameOrConnectionString)
    End Sub

    ' Controls the generation of the db model.
    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(New ADGroupConfiguration())
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(New GroupConfiguration())
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(New UserConfiguration())
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class UserConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of User)

    Public Sub New()
        ' Defining optional and required properties.
        [Property](Function(u) u.UserName).IsRequired()

        ' Defining n:m-relationships.
        HasMany(Function(u) u.UsersGroupsList).WithMany(Function(g) g.UserList)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ADGroupConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of ADGroup)

    Public Sub New()
        ' n:m-relationships.
        HasMany(Function(a) a.RelatedUsersList).WithMany(Function(u) u.UsersADGroupsList)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class GroupConfiguration
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of Group)

    Public Sub New()
        ' Defining 1:1-relationships.
        HasOptional(Function(g) g.RelatedADGroup).WithOptionalDependent(Function(a) a.RelatedGroup)

        ' Defining n:m-relationships.
        HasMany(Function(g) g.UserList).WithMany(Function(u) u.UsersGroupsList).Map(Sub(t)
                                                                                        t.ToTable("UsersGroups")
                                                                                    End Sub)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I am using Entity Framework 6.0.1 and Visual Studio 2013.

For me, there arise the following questions:

1. What am I doing wrong when updating the object (graph)?
2. My solution, though inspired by Lerman&Miller (2012, Programming Entity Framework: DBContext) looks overcomplicated to me. How to make it simpler?
3. How to handle exceptions? I assume that there will arise optimistic concurrency exceptions but I do not have any idea, how to handle them, as the exceptions do not return the object, which causes the exception. Due to the independent associations.

I am new to Entity Framework. So it is possible that there is a simple solution to my problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.